# TSQL - Get Item not duplicate in group and in Max group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have Data Table Example:

```
Declare @tb1 Table(ItemId int , GroupDuplicateId int, GroupType nvarchar(10))

Insert Into @tb1 Values(1,1,'IN'),(1,1,'VN'),(1,2,'IN'),(1,3,'IN'),(1,2,'VN'),(1,3,'VN'),(1,3,'SK')
Insert Into @tb1 Values(2,1,'IN'),(2,1,'VN')

select * from @tb1
Order by ItemId, GroupDuplicateId, GroupType
```

Now, I want get Items in 1 one group . 
Example: ItemId 1 have GroupDuplicateId: 1, 2 ,3 . We need one of thems.
         ItemId 2 satistify because, only 1 group.

```
Declare @tbResult1 Table(ItemId int , GroupDuplicateId int, GroupType nvarchar(10))

Insert Into @tbResult1 Values(1,1,'IN'),(1,1,'VN')  
Insert Into @tbResult1 Values(2,1,'IN'),(2,1,'VN')
select * from @tbResult1
```

--2. The same 1. But, we need Group 3. It's have 3 Group Type: IN, VN, SK.

```
    Insert Into @tbResult2 Values(1,3,'IN'),(1,3,'VN'),(1,3,'SK') -- Have max in Group
    Insert Into @tbResult2 Values(2,1,'IN'),(2,1,'VN')

select * from @tbResult2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking.  Please edit your question and show us clear input along with expected output.

Comment: yes, I did. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for .?

```
Declare @tb1 Table(ItemId int , GroupDuplicateId int, GroupType nvarchar(10))

Insert Into @tb1 Values(1,1,'IN'),(1,1,'VN'),(1,2,'IN'),(1,3,'IN'),(1,2,'VN'),(1,3,'VN'),(1,3,'SK')
Insert Into @tb1 Values(2,1,'IN'),(2,1,'VN')

/*
select * from @tb1
Order by ItemId, GroupDuplicateId, GroupType */

;with cte as (
select *,row_number()over(partition by itemid,GroupType order by itemid,GroupDuplicateId)rn from @tb1
)
select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: oh, Thank for your help Mahesh.K.  but it must be the same GroupDuplicateId. Mean, When you use GroupDuplicatedId = 3, Item 1 only use  GroupType in GroupDuplicatedId = 3. Not accept merge between 1 & 3 like your example.